# MVC Application hosting as a sub folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, .net-4.5, web-hosting

we have an already existing silverlight application within which we use "Role Provider" for setting permission to each available folders for browsing.

Typically, my requirement is this:

I have developed a MVC application which inturn should be placed ***as a folder inside the existing silverlight website ***.

I can be able to browse the folder but i really want my application to be launched when I browse this folder. Something like below,

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on `Silverlight WebSite`, then press `Add Application` button.

Setup your MVC application and it will appear inside `Silverlight WebSite`.

Comment: typically, my requirement is that I cannot have a mvc4 application inside a silverlight application. It just should exist as a folder.

Comment: You must host MVC4 as an application because it requires app pool. What's wrong with having a nested mvc application inside silverlight?

Comment: Just wanted to know if that is possible! It's typically my client's requirement just because everytime I give him a new mvc4 application files, she can just place that in a folder!

Comment: It is possible to fit the requirenment of your client. When you create a new sub application inside a web site, you can specify a path to any folder you need. In all upcoming updates in the future you can just replace files in that folder.